# Store RSS into DB

Tags: asp.net

I developing a website where i need to read the RSS feeds from users blogs,websites and store it in database. To have clear understanding, i have seen dotnetslackers reads the rSS from asp.net forums and other webistes and publishes it. Is it some batch process that reads every day and dumps into the DB?? Any way to implement it without batch?? since, i cant use a batch in shared hosting environment..

Regards,
Babu

Answer (score 1):

if using SQL 2005+ it is quite easy ...

create a new column of type **XML** and insert there your feed.

in your ASP.NET page, pass the parameter to your SP like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertFeed", conn);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

...

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@AllXml", System.Data.SqlDbType.Xml).Value = myFeedString;
```

---

Regarding the batch process, you can easily use the Task Manager in your PC to execute your ASP.NET script in the server to process it or [use the ASP.net cache to run the process periodically as Jeff Atwood suggests](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/)

There are several ways to do this, and they all depend in your output.

Comment: Hi balexandre,
Thanks for the reply. I undersatnd we can do like this but i want the new posts in RSS to be updated automatically in the DB.

Comment: you have to realize that the DB does not do this by it self, you need to do it manually. Create an aspx page only with Page_Load event and start from there to update what you need. DO that in a matter that when you open that page all the updates will occur (get the RSS file and dump it into the DB). Now all you need to do is set Task Manager to run that page every hour for example... and you will have in the DB a fresh RSS every hour.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always add a button to your webapp and reread all feeds in `Click` handler. Be advised, though, that the process which will be rereading these feeds can be recycled almost anytime due to standard ASP.NET recycling procedure. If you need a reliable way of reading feeds, Windows Service (or just a scheduled task) will be much nicer.